# FireFox marketplace in-app payments

Tags: firefox, firefox-os, marketplace

I have added FireFox Marketplace in-app payments to my game pathuku using fxPay.

Everything seems to be working when i use the fakeProducts setting below:

```
fxpay.configure({fakeProducts: true});
```

When i try to use fxPay in Live i get the following in my console:

message

```
23:30:46.305 "opening" "GET" "to" "https://marketplace.firefox.com/api/v1/payments/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pathuku.com/in-app/?active=1"1 fxpay.min.js:1:4761
```

error

```
23:30:46.681 "XHR error event:" error { target: XMLHttpRequest, isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, currentTarget: XMLHttpRequest, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, defaultPrevented: false, timeStamp: 1432593046679000 }1 fxpay.min.js:1:4078
```

error

```
23:30:46.690 "Error getting products:ApiRequestError: received XHR error for path: /payments/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pathuku.com/in-app/?active=1"1 main.js:1:10765
_eo/b.e5.fxpay.checkForPurcs/<() main.js:1
z() fxpay.min.js:1
A() fxpay.min.js:1
x() fxpay.min.js:1
t() fxpay.min.js:1
j() fxpay.min.js:1
```

A http OPTIONS request is made to

```
https://marketplace.firefox.com/api/v1/payments/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pathuku.com/in-app/?active=1
```

The url seems to be working, but i don't understand why only a OPTIONS request is being made?

My game url is

```
https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/pathuku/
https://www.pathuku.com
```

Any help would be very welcome

Comment: I played your game a few months ago. Its very fun. It was front pgae. L(

Comment: It's unclear why it's not working. This might have something to do with how the request is sent. As it's doing an OPTIONS request, I guess it might be a problem with CORS. I had a similar problem with my browser sending extra headers that the server wouldn't accept. As you don't have control over the server, make sure that you're request isn't sending anything more than what the OPTIONS request tell you that you can. "access-control-allow-headers"

Answer (score 0):

This problem was being caused by the orignal JSON library, it added functions to the Object.prototype. This in turn caused the  fxpay serialisation code to break. As JSON has been added to most browsers, I removed the reference  to the old libabry and everything is now working.